# Is it necessary to optimize my Durandal application build if I'm using Adobe PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, durandal, phonegap-build

I have a Durandal application that I'm building using Adobe PhoneGap Build. Should I optimize the build [as described here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Native-Apps-With-PhoneGap-Cordova/) or is it sufficient to build it in PhoneGap Build with the debug option off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always good to have a lean framework related footprint for your applications. I have not personally worked with Durandal on PhoneGap, but if there is an option for improving the performance, you can always go for it.

Comment: Do you know that PhoneGap build is not performing the same (or better) optimizations than building with Weyland?

Comment: I am not sure how Weyland does that. But the Ant build tool used by default in cordova projects, does not provide any optimizations.

Comment: Weyland (with default config) runs [Uglify](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) to minimize App & Durandal code. Then [RequireJs Optomizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to combine the scripts, it also substitutes Almond for the RequireJs AMD loader.